# How to find which landline wires are mine using sensors on my cell phone?

Tags: wire, detection, magnetometer

[image: My phone line is in there, somewhere]

How do I figure out which one is my line? I know there's a special tool for it, some sort of beeping proximity sensor. I don't want to buy any tools.

My cell phone, like many, has a Magnetometer. Should it get a louder reading if I dial out on the landline at the same time for example?

Comment: I can guarantee that your phone DOES NOT have a [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer).

Comment: short out wire pairs, one pair at a time, while listening to your landline phone

Comment: @Andyaka: How can you guarantee that? Many phones do. Have you never seen a [compass app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/compass/id520985073)?

Comment: @DaveTweed if it was a cell phone, the wiring wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis: The OP is asking whether he can use the magnetometer in his cell phone to determine which pair of wires is connected to his landline phone. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: It's clear, it's just... unlikely.  Maybe with very low level access and a slow excitation source.

Comment: it makes no sense to be asking your question ... you can simply verify your theory by testing the wire leading from the wall to your phone set

Comment: @jsotola it snakes through walls and I have no idea how it gets to that junction. It's very dirty cause it's right on the street. Soot from cars and shit ..

Comment: @Slabo, it makes no difference how is snakes through the wall ... it ends up in your appartment ... test it there ... if your cell phone cannot detect it in your apartment, then it won't be able to detect it on the street either

Comment: Pro’s use an RF signal finder with a sender on the pair.

Comment: @DaveTweed I get it now.  It would be easier to use a magnetometer if the two active wires were separated, but with them both together in the cable it'll be more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of to do without using a line-mans phone is to bring a telephone to that jumble and connect it to each line one at a time and call the number that reads back the line number. I don't know what it is in your area or provider, but there should be a 3 digit number you can dial on any landline and it will read back the number of the line to you.

Comment: you don't have to call any number from the landline ... just call your landline phone from your cell phone ... if the landline phone rings, then you are probably on the correct wire pair

Comment: I think this should be the answer because according to @DaveTweed seems you'll need to loop the sensor around one cable at a time.